# After form submit redirect without refresh using Ajax in laravel 8

Tags: ajax, laravel-8, ajaxform

I am developing multi Step Form Submit without refresh. collect the data from 1st step 2nd step collect some date, 3rd step collect some date & finally submit data in the database. Can you tell me how to fix this.

My blade template.

```
<form id="post-form" method="post" action="javascript:void(0)">                                    
                                      @csrf     
      <div>

  <input class="form-input" type="text" id="ptitle" name="ptitle" required="required"  
    placeholder="What do you want to achieve?">
      </div>

                               
                                        <button type="text" id="send_form" class="btn-continue">Continue</button>
                                 
                                    </div>
                                </form>
```

Ajax Script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#send_form").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
         var _token = $("input[name='_token']").val();
         var ptitle = $('#ptitle').val();

            $.ajax({
                url: "{{route('create.setp2') }}",
                method:'POST',
                data: {_token:_token,ptitle:ptitle},
                success: function(data) {
                   
                   alert('data.success');

                }
            });
       
        });
```

Web.php router

```
Route::post('/setp2', [Abedoncontroller::class, 'funcsetp1'])->name('create.setp2');
```

Controller method

```
public function funcsetp1(Request $request) {

     $postdata=$request->input('ptitle');
      
     return response()->json('themes.abedon.pages.create-step-2');
    }
```